# Mysql Procedure does nothing?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a task where for every column in every view of my mysql db if i have special characters or lowercase letters, i need to transform those letters to uppercase, and change special charaters with underscore, thing is, i have a procedure, but does nothing? I mean, i created it succesfully, call it, returns nothing, columns stays the same even they need to change... what i'm doing wrong?

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ModifyViewColumns()
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE v_def TEXT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT table_name, view_definition
        FROM information_schema.views
        WHERE table_schema = 'petru_views';
    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO v_name, v_def;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name)
        INTO @columns
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE table_schema = 'petru_views' AND table_name = v_name;
        
 
        SET @new_def = REPLACE(v_def, @columns, UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(@columns, '[ #$\\-\.]', '_')));
        

        SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ', v_name, ' AS ', @new_def);
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP read_loop;
    
    CLOSE cur;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL ModifyViewColumns();
```

Comment: `@columns` will not be found in `v_def` because the `view_definition` contains fully qualified (and quoted) columns (`\`db_name\`.\`tbl_name\`.\`col_name\` AS \`col_name\``), whereas `@columns` is just a comma separated string of column names (`col1,col2,col3`). Are you trying to update the column identifiers, the aliases, or both? `information_schema.columns.column_name` has the alias name, not the name of the underlying column. You should add an example of the `view_definition` of a view you are expecting to be updated, and exactly what you expect it to be updated to.